# How to handle varargs with NativeCall

Tags: c, raku, nativecall

I'm writing bindings for Editline; one of its functions, [`history`](http://cvsweb.netbsd.org/bsdweb.cgi/src/lib/libedit/history.c?rev=1.63&content-type=text/x-cvsweb-markup&sortby=date), does the bulk of the work for this part of the library, but has several possible signatures:

```
:(Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32)
:(Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, int32 --> int32)
:(Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, Str --> int32)
# etc.
```

The third argument is a flag that determines which function `history` should call with the arguments given, but since those symbols aren't exported, I have no way of using them instead. How can I find a way to use the function? I can't use multi subs or use `cglobal` to cast it to a `Pointer`, then to a function with the right signature.

*Edit*: I know about [`is symbol`](https://docs.raku.org/language/nativecall#Changing_names), but I'm wondering if there are any better ways to go about this since there are 9 different signatures to write for.

Comment: Are you looking for this: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/va_arg.3p.html?

Comment: the history function likely uses va_arg internally, but this is about how to call into it via perl6's FFI library, which sadly currently has no explicit support for variable arg functions. Until that support lands, I would suggest generating a bunch of alternative subs with EVAL and exporting a sub that calls the right variant.

Comment: Yeah, that's what the function uses, but there's no interface for it in NativeCall as far as I know

Comment: Looks like I was late, but I'll give that a shot

Comment: Nothing  I can write for this works. Calling `history` only works if just one subroutine is ever defined for it; when there's more than one, calling it makes MoarVM segfault when `va_start` is called internally, no matter whether it's built with Dyncall or LibFFI. I'll need to post an issue for this

Comment: Which symbols are not exported? By whom?

Comment: Have you tried again lately?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could wrap the native function with a Raku function:

```raku
sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, int32 $flag, $c? --> int32 ){
  given $flag {
    when 0|2 {
      sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
      history( $a, $b, $flag )
    }
    when 1|3 {
      sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
      history( $a, $b, $flag, $c )
    }
    when 4 {
      sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, Str --> int32) is native(…) {}
      history( $a, $b, $flag, $c )
    }
  }
}
```

---

Or you could wrap each version in its own multi:

```raku
# Note the flag value ---------------------------------------+
#                                                            |
#                                                            V
multi sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, 0 --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 0 )
}
multi sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, 2 --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 2 )
}

multi sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, int32 $flag where 1|3, int32 $c --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, $flag, $c )
}

multi sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, 4, Str:D $c --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, Str --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 4, $c )
}
```

---

You might even be able to determine the correct flag to give based on the arguments. This would only work if there is only one flag for each signature.
(So this following example does not follow the above where `0` and `2` have the same signature.)

```raku
multi sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 0 )
}

multi sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, int32 $c --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 1, $c )
}

multi sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, Str:D $c --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, Str --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 4, $c )
}
```

---

You could write wrappers with different names:

```raku
sub foo ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 0 )
}

sub bar ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, int32 $c --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32 --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 1, $c )
}

sub baz ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, Str:D $c --> int32 ){
  sub history (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, Str --> int32) is native(…) {}
  history( $a, $b, 4, $c )
}
```

---

You could do that without wrappers by using `is symbol`.

```raku
sub foo (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32        --> int32) is native(…) is symbol<history> {}
sub bar (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, int32 --> int32) is native(…) is symbol<history> {}
sub baz (Pointer[Internal], Pointer[Event], int32, Str   --> int32) is native(…) is symbol<history> {}
```

---

You could also use `nativecast` and a generated Signature object in your wrapper function:

```raku
sub history ( Pointer[Internal] $a, Pointer[Event] $b, int32 $flag, $c? --> int32 ){
  my \I32 = Parameter.new( type => int32 );
  my \PI  = Parameter.new( type => Pointer[Internal] );
  my \PE  = Parameter.new( type => Pointer[Event] );
  my \STR = Parameter.new( type => Str );

  my @params = ( PI, PE, I32 );
  given $flag {
    when 0|2 {
    }
    when 1|3 {
      @params.push( I32 );
    }
    when 4 {
      @params.push( STR );
    }
  }

  my \signature = Signature.new( params => @params.List, returns => int32 );

  # fill this out -----------V
  my \history-ptr = cglobal( …, 'history', Pointer );

  my &history = nativecast( signature, history-ptr );

  history( $a, $b, $flag, ($c if +@params == 4) );
}
```

This is how you might write a wrapper for C’s `printf` or `scanf`.

---

Regardless of which of the above you use, you need some way to determine which variation you need to call.

Even in C, there has to be a way to determine the number and type of arguments based on the current, or a previous argument.

In `printf` the number and type of arguments is based on the the first argument which is the format.

A C function could determine the number of arguments by having a trailing null argument. In which case you have to tell Raku that.

Regardless of how the underlying foreign function handles `va_args`, you have to copy that algorithm into Raku in some form. It can't just guess.

If you had several foreign functions that all worked similarly, you could create a wrapper generator for them.